# No acceleration tab QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, linux, gpgpu, gpu, opencl

[image]

I don't have the acceleration tab in QGIS:

QGIS: 3.10.1-A Coruña

Nvidia driver: 440.44

Graphics card: RTX 2070 super

Cuda: 10.2.89-3

Operative system: manjaro - Linux

Edit, i also don't see any option related to GPU acceleration in the rendering tab:

[image]
[image]

Edit 2, I am also don't see any OpenCL in `Advanced > core`, using the search bar doesn't show any OpenCL options either.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the `Rendering` tab (4 tabs below the `General` tab) for processor and video card optimization / settings ?

Comment: @j-monticolo, I am new to QGIS but as far as i know there should be a tab for enabling acceleration like [this](https://www.itopen.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/qigs_opencl_options.png).

Comment: @j-monticolo, I also don't see any option relating to OpenCL i am not sure of  what could be wrong.

Comment: I miss some details : `Advanced` tab, `core` line to deploy, last lines refer to `OpenCL` parameters.

Comment: I have 3.10.1 installed using the standalone installer and I have the Acceleration tab.  How did you install Qgis?  From which file?  Windows, Linux, or Mac?

Comment: @GreyHippo I tested the version in the official repositories and flatpak one, none of then work.

Comment: I just did a recent install using the standalone 64 bit Windows installer that was downloaded this morning.

Comment: I've got the same problem, so if you ever get it solved, I'd be interested. QGIS 3.10 on archlinux 5.4.15, 64bit, nvidia 440.44 driver, opencl-nvidia

Comment: @GeckoGeorge, check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building QGIS from AUR solved the problem.

[image]

[image]

AUR package: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/qgis-git/